# Excepciones Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Necesito una forma de poder ejecutar una excepcion, pero aqui hay algo distinto. Quiero que se ejecute lo que dado el caso que caiga en la excepcion , se ejecute lo que yo programo dentro del bloque del catch.

```
try{
//Success
}catch(Exception ex){
//Codigo que necesito ejecutar
}
```

Pero he estado viendo lo que hay en el handler del proyecto y la excepcion 'Exception' esta definida como sigue:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Config;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && $request->wantsJSON()) {
            $modelName = $exception->getModel();
            $className = substr($modelName, strrpos($modelName, '\\') + 1);
            $modelIds = implode(', ', $exception->getIds());

            return response()->json([
                Config::get('constants.response.CODE') => Config::get('constants.code.HTTP_NOT_FOUND'),
                Config::get('constants.response.MESSAGE') =>
                    $className.' '.$modelIds.' '.Lang::get('generalAPI.NOT_FOUND'),
                Config::get('constants.response.DATA') => []
            ], Config::get('constants.code.HTTP_NOT_FOUND'));
        }

        if ($exception instanceof Exception) {
            return 0;
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

Esta definido que solamente retorne un cero, hasta donde entiendo esto no deberia afectarme. 
Pero al construir el try&catch en el controlador, ahí si agrego una linea badResponse que corresponde a una mala respuesta del servidor.

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
    try {
        $user = User::with('userInfo')->find($id);
        return SuccessResponse($user->with('userInfo')->find($user->id), Lang::get('messages.FOUND'));
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        return BadResponse(Lang::get('messages.NOT_FOUND'));  //Esto es lo que necesito que se ejecute, no lo que tiene internamente 'Exception'
    }
}
```

Entonces al probar el endpoint que apunta al metodo show (solo es uno de tantos que necesito homologar sus respuestas) , Postman me responde así:

[image: El endpoint responde 0]

Entiendo que responda 0 por que eso esta en la definicion de la excepcion 'Exception', pero en realidad lo que necesito es que se ejecute el badResponse que defino en el controlador en el bloque catch despues de haber caido en la excepcion.

Resumiendo: En caso de caer en la excepcion, necesito que me haga el badResponse y no me retorne solamente el 0 que Postman me muestra.

Algun entendido de Laravel que me pueda ayudar, le estaré agradecido.

Gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro de entender del todo tu pregunta, así que cualquier cosa editala y avisame.

En el método show tenés un `catch`, pero no estás generando ninguna `exception`, con lo cual nunca se va a ejecutar dicho bloque. En vez de utilizar [`find()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) tendrías que usar [`findOrFail()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-single-models). Éste segundo método genera une excepción si no se encuentra ningún resultado:

> if no result is found, a `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException` will be thrown

Lo que le pases como parámetro al `catch` va a determinar si querés que se ejecute cuando se genere *cualquier* excepción o específicamente la del `findOrFail()`.

---

**Ejemplo agarrando cualquier excepción:**

```
try {
    $user = User::with('userInfo')->findOrFail($id);

    return SuccessResponse($user, Lang::get('messages.FOUND'));
} catch (\Exception $ex) {
    return BadResponse(Lang::get('messages.NOT_FOUND'));
}
```

Le paso como parámetro a catch [`\Exception`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.exception.php), que es la clase genérica de PHP para las excepciones, con lo cual cualquier excepción que se genere va a ser *agarrada* por el catch.

---

**Ejemplo agarrando una excepción específica:**

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

...

try {
    $user = User::with('userInfo')->findOrFail($id);

    return SuccessResponse($user, Lang::get('messages.FOUND'));
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
    return BadResponse(Lang::get('messages.NOT_FOUND'));
}
```

Al especificar como parámetro `ModelNotFoundException`, el catch se va a ejecutar solo si se genera esa excepción, no otras.